# ggplot2 two fills with two different variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to make a stacked bar plot where I have one colour for each "company" and that colour divided in three for each sport. I have tried to use `alpha` which I can't seem to get to work anyway, but I would prefer to use colour themes instead.
I have submitted code with data i've made up to practice the steps that I have done with the "real" data. If you have suggestions of how to make this easier, do not hesitate. 
Thank you in advance.

```
x1<-c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
x2<-c("Hej", "Hopp", "i Galopp", "Hopp", "i Galopp", "Hej", "i Galopp", "Hej", 
"Hopp", "Hej")
x3<-c(301, 5, 4, 26, 19, 82, 111, 41, 29, 12)
x4<-c(52, 43, 5, 23, 7, 88, 45, 2, 44, 56)
x5<-c(99, 4, 41, 77, 82, 71, 66, 203, 43, 40)
mydf<-data.frame(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)
names(mydf)<-c("ID", "Company" , "Swim", "Bike", "Run")

mydf_prop<-prop.table(as.matrix(mydf[,3:5]),1)
mydf_prop<- mydf_prop %>% round(digits=2)
mydf_prop<-cbind.data.frame("Company"=mydf[,2], mydf_prop)
mydf_prop<-cbind.data.frame("ID"=mydf[,1], mydf_prop)
mydf_prop[,3:5]<-mydf_prop[,3:5]*100
mydf_prop<-mydf_prop %>% gather(`Swim`, `Bike`, `Run`, key = "Sport", 
                                value = "Sales in %") %>% arrange(`ID`)

mydf_prop %>% ggplot(aes(`ID`, `Sales in %`, fill=Company, alpha(Sport)))+
geom_col()+ geom_text(aes(`ID`, `Sales in %`, label=paste0(`Sales in %`, "%")), 
                    position = position_stack(vjust = 1), size =3)+
scale_alpha_manual(values=c(0.1, 0.5, 1)) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,10,1))+ coord_flip()
```

Comment: Try `fill = interaction(Company, Sport), alpha = Sport`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "colour divided in three", but a slight change to your code for `alpha` produces the following.  This is probably the easiest approach unless you want to get into the really nitty gritty of adjusting hues by Sport.

```
mydf_prop %>% 
  ggplot(aes(`ID`, `Sales in %`, fill=Company, alpha = Sport))+
  geom_col()+ 
  geom_text(aes(`ID`, `Sales in %`, label=paste0(`Sales in %`, "%")), 
                        position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 3)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,10,1))+ 
  scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(0.5, 1))+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot , but..... the "bike" part is too transparent to be able to read the plot easily. Is there anyway to adjust that? I guessed that that was going to happen hence the wish for coloured themes. But I am very grateful.

Comment: @Mactilda: edited to add a better scale for the alpha parameter